# SSRS 2012 right aligned text cut off

Tags: reporting-services, bids, ssrs-2012

We recently upgraded from SSRS 2008 R2 to SSRS 2012.  A good portion of our existing reports are now rendering with some columns cutting off right-aligned text.

We used BIDS 2008 to develop the reports and then deploy the RDL's to SSRS 2012 server.

I cannot replicate the issue locally, which leads me to believe there is some server configuration that could be changed.

I've verified that the fonts used are installed on the server.

Anyone have any ideas?

**Update**

Simply adding 2pt right indent to the affected textboxes prevents the cutoff. This is obviously a band aid, and it would be better to determine the actual cause and fix.

Answer (score 3):

Adding an indent does work, but for us it made the column headers not in sync with the data.

I set `ShrinkToFit = true`.

That fixed the problem without moving it over.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue on a new RDLC 2012 report. Though not all numbers were cut. Thanks to andy I was able to focus on the `CanGrow` and `CanShrink` Properties of the Cell. I had set `CanGrow=False` and `CanShrink=False`. Setting either of this to true did fix the issue.